# How would I calculate the expected value in this situation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Given $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and a map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{r}_{+}$

I would like to calculate

$$ \mathbb{E}[\phi(x)^{T}\phi(y)] $$

I am unsure if you need to make the map explicit. If so, let $r=1$ and $\phi(x)=|x^{T}x|$ for simplicity.

Is it possible to get an expected value here? If not, what more information would I need?

In case it provides clarity, this question comes from my reading of this paper, section 2.2: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14794

EDIT: For further clarity, here is the general definition of $\phi$

Given $f_{1},...f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$g: \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$

deterministic vectors $\omega_1 ... \omega_m \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I}_d)$

$$ \phi(x) = \frac{h(x)}{\sqrt m} (f_1(\omega_1^{T} x), ..., f_1(\omega_m^{T}x), ...,f_n(\omega_1^{T} x), ..., f_n(\omega_m^{T}x)) $$

Would this be explicit enough to give me a general formula for calculating the expected value?

Comment: When we talk about expected value, we should have random variable somewhere!

Comment: Leon, that is exactly why I am so confused. These objects and equations, besides the explicit map I defined, come from the paper.

I will edit and provide the general definition of $\phi$ presented. That's probably where I am stumbling.